# How to maintain request in Angular?

Tags: angular, http, request, message-queue

I have this function to save objects in service In angular application.

```
save(object: Object): Observable<Book> {
  return this.http.put(this.baseUrl, object);
}
```

As we all know that http request isasynchronous and may take time more than we expected.

Under this circumstance, if I call this function `save(object: Object)` frequently. It will happen that the last request hasn't been completed and the next request has already been sent. This will cause problems.

The object I want to save have some unique constraints like name and optimistic lock.

See some cases below: with **obj1** and **obj2**

**Case 1:** obj
obj1 and obj2 has the same name but diferent ID;

```
obj1 {
  id: 1;
  name: 'name1';
  optimisticLock: 0;
}
```

```
obj2 {
  id: 2;
  name: 'name1';
  optimictic: 0;
}
```

In this case, if obj1 has been sent by http but hasn't been completed yet, then obj2 is been sent too. For obj2, server side will check if name is duplicated. Although we can see that obj1 and obj2 has the same name, but because that obj1 hasn't been saved yet, obj2 name check will pass. So obj2 name unique check passed, but still save failed, and server side will throw unique constraint exception.

**Case 2**
If obj1 and obj2 are the same data but with different name like this:

```
obj1 {
  id: 0;
  name: 'previousName';
  optimisticLock: 0;
}
```

```
obj2 {
  id: 0;
  name: 'newName';
  optimisticLock: 0;
}
```

Send obj1 first and then send obj2 to save. obj1 saved and server side return value like this

```
obj1 {
  id: 0;
  name: 'previousName';
  optimisticLock: 1;
}
```

It will update it's optimistic lock 0 -> 1; But this response hasn't been back to client yet, so obj2 optimisticLock is still 0 and sent to server side. So apparently, the request to save obj2 will fail.

What we expected is to save the last modification, but we only saved obj1. So this is a serious problem.

I have an idea to sovle these 2 cases. If I use a Queue to put all requests. All requests must be put into this queue, and this queue sends the first request, before getting response from the first request, no other request would be sent. After the first request respond, update this queue according to the response. Then send second request.

But I don't know how to code this solution, anyone knows how to do this? Or do you have better solution to solve the problems in case1 and case2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use rxjs to solve that problem. You have to provide an trigger based on a subject which then calls the save method.

Example:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  save(object: Object): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.put('some-url', object);
  }

}

@Component({})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  save$: Subject<Object> = new Subject();

  constructor(private service: MyService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.save$.pipe(concatMap(o => this.service.save(o)))
  }

  save(object: Object) {
    this.save$.next(object);
  }

}
```

There are several rxjs/operators to handle incoming events.

- **concatMap**
  handles incoming events sequentially. In your case it waits until your http request is finished and then does the next one. So basically your queue
- **switchMap**
  unsubscibes from inner observable and handles the next event. This means the current httpCall gets cancelled and the next one will be executed. In the end the last save would win
- **mergeMap**
  everytime an event comes in a new inner observable will be created and subscribed. That means all your requests will be executed regardless if the previous one was completed or not.
- **exhaustMap**
  This is the don't interrupt me operator. When the inner observable is not finished it ignores all incoming new events.

The inner observable is your httpCall basically and the outer observable is your subject. In this example I used concatMap that would be handling all incoming save actions sequentially, so like a queue.

Comment: question is: how do I update the queue according to the last response?